# Using same functions in 2 different controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am trying to reuse a few bigger functions over 3 controllers in Angular JS. I don't want to pin the functions to my root scope as I want to keep it clear of functions which will be used only 3 times within those 3 controllers.

```
    angular.module('adminModule', ['adminDependency'])

        .controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'details', function ($scope, details) {
            // use functions
        }])

        .controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'details', function ($scope, details) {
            // use functions
        }])

        .controller('ctrl3', ['$scope', 'details', function ($scope, details) {
            // use functions
        }])
```

Can you tell me how i can achieve that without writing my functions into the root scope?

Tried it inside a factory but calling AdminModule.toLevelKey() wont work...

```
    .factory('AdminModule',
        [ '$resource', 'serviceURL', function ($resource, serviceURL) {

            return $resource(serviceURL + 'class/:id', {
                    id : '@id'
                }, {
                    getClasses : {
                        method  : 'GET',
                        url     : serviceURL + 'extended/class',
                        isArray : true
                    },

                    toLevelKey : function (value) {
                        var return_key = parseInt(Math.floor(value / 3));
                        var return_level = value % 3;

                        return { level : return_level + 1, levelTranslationKey : return_key + 1 };
                    },

                    fromLevelKey : function (level, key) {
                        if (angular.isDefined(level)) {
                            var value = (key - 1) * 3 + (level - 1);

                            return value;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        } ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with the above comment of David Fariña: "Are there even more options?".

Except executing, you also can pass data from one controller to another and broadcast event, when it happens.

SharedService:

```
    angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("mySharedService", function($rootScope){

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = {};

        mySharedService.setValues = function(params){
            mySharedService.values = params;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed');
        }

        return mySharedService; 
   });
```

FirstController:

```
 function FirstCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
      $scope.passDataInSharedSevice = function(params){
         mySharedService.setValues(params);
      }
 }
```

SecondController:

```
 function SecondController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.$on('dataPassed', function () {
        $scope.newItems = mySharedService.values;
    });
 }
```

Comment: Can the downvoter tell what is wrong with this please?

Comment: @DavidFariña, I think, that downvoter means, that answer not corresponding to question. I add this answer on your comment: "Are there even more options?"
The answer contains nothing wrong.

Comment: i actually ended up doing it that way as i wasnt able to inject the service where i needed to. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

This can be done by a service:

```
.service('myService', function(){
   return {
      fn: function(){
        // do what you want
      }
   }
});
```

usage:

```
.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'details', 'myService', 
             function ($scope, details, myService) {
   // use functions
   myService.fn();
}])
```

Comment: Seems like a very good solution. Are there even more options?

Comment: you may use a factory. but the principle is the same; especially if you need other services in your function. in this case you can easily inject them.

Comment: Just in case you need setting some params for details you should use a provider.

Comment: I do need to pass params. I tried to assign the service functions to the scope but somehow calling AdminService.func(param1, param2) does not work. throwed a infdig error.
Edit: I used it inside a factory, is it possible that way?

Comment: please show more details (code) what your are trying to do.